# Why is WorkManager fired multiple times as soon as my app starts?

Tags: android, kotlin, background, intervals, worker

I have an app in which I have declared a WorkManager, and the doWork() overrided function is called 3 or 4 times as soon as my app starts, without asking for the system to start it at any time in the code...

I have checked that no reference to the WorkManager would have been done in the application. There is only one in App.kt file (that extends Application()).

In App.kt :

```
class App : Application(){

companion object {
    var appSyncRepository = AppSyncRepository()
}
}
```

In AppSyncRepository.kt :

```
class AppSyncRepository {
}

class AppSyncRepositoryWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
override fun doWork(): Result {
    return Result.success()
}
}
```

I would expect the worker not to be called because I have neither declared any OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder nor any PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder for now.

Comment: Have you ever had any `PeriodicWorkRequest` in your app before? Even if you remove `PeriodicWorkRequest` and re-install your app, the `PeriodicWorkRequest` you already queued will not be destroyed unless you cancel it. All your periodic work will be called at the application process startup. Also, it seems there are multiple request of the same job are queued. Use `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork` to avoid duplicate works.

Comment: No, I have not added any code neither with PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder nor OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder.

Comment: I think that Sanlok Lee is true, after having analyzed this issue (some months ago), and if I remember well, what you wrote is the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to comment.

In your testing did you set a PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder request? If so you have to cancel it.

As a first step I would check to see what is scheduled.

```
void cancelJob(){
    WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).cancelAllWorkByTag(SYNC_WORK_JOB1);
    WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).cancelAllWork();
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled!");
}

private boolean isWorkScheduled() {
WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance(mContext);
    ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> statuses = instance.getWorkInfosByTag(SYNC_WORK_JOB1);
    try {
        boolean running = false;
        List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = statuses.get();
        for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
            WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
            running = state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING | state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;
        }
        return running;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you could run in a terminal window

```
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler | grep -C 5 SyncWorkManagerService
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler | grep -B 10 "Pending queue"
```

Comment: What is **SyncWorkManagerService**?